# How to load multiline records into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, delimiter, line-breaks

I am trying to loading multiple log files which have similar format but one record can be in multiple lines I have done some development but reading each line separately is taking too much time 
the sample code is as follows.

**Please help me**

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'eventtime':[],
                    'FileType':[],
                    'msg_type':[],
                    'thred_num':[],
                    'msg_lyr':[], 
                    'message':[],
                    'colorcode':[]
                    })
def write_line(record,file_type):
    if record=='':
        return

    split1= record.split("[")
    split2 = split1[0].split(" ")
    split3 = split1[1].split(" ")
    split4 = split1[2]

    s_time = split2[1].split(",")
    str_dateime  = split2[0] + ' ' + s_time[0] + "."+s_time[1]

    df.loc[len(df)] = pd.Series( {'eventtime':str_dateime,
                    'FileType':file_type,
                    'msg_type':split2[2],
                    'thred_num':split3[0][:-1],
                    'msg_lyr':split3[1], 
                    'message':split4,
                    'colorcode':""
                    })

for si_file in si_Files:
    f= gzip.open(si_file,'rt') 
    file_content = f.read()
    f.close()
    for record in file_content .split("]~~\n"):**
        write_line(record,'silogs')'''
```

Is there a better way i can load the data in DataFrame reading file line by line and then loading it into data frame is too much resource expensinve specaillay on the Application server where primary application is running

The sample log file is as follows

```
2019-12-02 08:53:26,261 INFO  [18] CTL.CONF     - [Loading Configurations]~~<br>
2019-12-02 08:53:26,273 DEBUG [18] trg.sm.cs.client.CfgInterface - [Start: |User:default|ClientMachine:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:26,274 DEBUG [18] trg.sm.cs.client.CfgInterface - [Start: Waiting for connection with configuration server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:X000]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:26,328 INFO  [19] GSI.Comms.SC - [Connecting|xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:x000]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:26,329 WARN  [19] GSI.Comms.SC - [Fast Loopback enabled]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:27,334 ERROR [19] GSI.Comms.SC - [Failed to connect with <br/>server|Endpoint:xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:x000|Error:No connection could be made because the target <br/>machine actively refused it xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:x000(ConnectionRefused:10061)]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:30,340 INFO  [19] GSI.Comms.SC - [Connecting|xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:x000]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:30,341 WARN  [19] GSI.Comms.SC - [Fast Loopback enabled]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:30,393 WARN  [19] sm.cs.client.CfgInterface - [Start: No QueryReload performed, EngineId missing.]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:30,393 DEBUG [19] sm.cs.client.CfgInterface - [ClientConnection |  Connected to the Server : Primary]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:30,393 DEBUG [18] sm.cs.client.CfgInterface - [Start: done.]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:30,512 DEBUG [13] CTL.CONF     - [ReloadResponse: Submitted]~~<br/>
**2019-12-02 08:53:31,791 INFO  [18] CTL.CONF     - [GroupSettingsXml|<Groups><br/>
xml tages EventProcessingLagThreshold 100 /EventProcessingLagThreshold <br/>
  XML tages QueueLengthThreshold 100 /QueueLengthThreshold <br/>
xml tags/Groups]~~<br/>**
2019-12-02 08:53:31,803 INFO  [18] CTL.CONF     - [EventProcessingLagThreshold:100]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:32,122 INFO  [18] SM.ENG.SatmapEngineCommonLibrary.Emailingclient.EmailAlerts - [Alerts Initialized with SMTPserver: 10.80.10.141, SMTPport: , Recipients: ssadaasd,  Sender Address: noreply-aasdlabaasd]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,856 INFO  [35] PRO.0.Q-AS-R - [QueryStatusResponse|ASC|AID:70032|DN:20029|CS:client_MODE_UNKNOWN=>client_MODE_READY|TS:TALK_STATE_UNKNOWN=>TALK_STATE_AVAILABLE]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,863 INFO  [31] CTL          - [HandleclientStatusEvent(client_MODE_READY)|AID:70032|KeepFreeclientOrder:False|ER:SUCCESSFULL]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,871 DEBUG [27] GSI.Comms.CM - [Tx|0|clientFree|MsgId:22|D-CID:1]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 DEBUG [24] TSP.EF       - [Rx|QUERY_TOD_RESPONSE|INV-ID:20|TOD:12/02/2019 11:53:41]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 DEBUG [35] PRO.0        - [Pr|QUERY_TOD_RESPONSE]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 DEBUG [35] PRO.0        - [RR|QueryTodRequest|INV-ID:20|08:53:41 808,08:53:41 817,08:53:41 899|RTT:90.98ms|PT:8.97]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 INFO  [35] PRO.0        - [CR|QueryTodRequest(ToCheckIfSkillMonitorCompleted)|S:80029|Pass:3]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 DEBUG [24] TSP.EF       - [Rx|QUERY_TOD_RESPONSE|INV-ID:21|TOD:12/02/2019 11:53:41]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 DEBUG [35] PRO.0        - [Pr|QUERY_TOD_RESPONSE]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 DEBUG [35] PRO.0        - [RR|QueryTodRequest|INV-ID:21|08:53:41 814,08:53:41 820,08:53:41 899|RTT:85.01ms|PT:6]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,899 INFO  [36] TSP.0.1      - [Tx|QueryTime]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,900 INFO  [36] PRO.0.RM     - [RP|QueryTodRequest|INV-ID:22|ICheckRequest:False|SkillId:80029(Pass:3)]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,903 INFO  [36] PRO.0        - [ST|OR Count:0|PR Count:1]~~
2019-12-02 08:53:41,950 DEBUG [24] TSP.EF       - [Rx|QUERY_TOD_RESPONSE|INV-ID:22|TOD:12/02/2019 11:53:41]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,950 DEBUG [35] PRO.0        - [Pr|QUERY_TOD_RESPONSE]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,950 DEBUG [35] PRO.0        - [RR|QueryTodRequest|INV-ID:22|08:53:41 899,08:53:41 899,08:53:41 950|RTT:51ms|PT:]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,950 INFO  [35] PRO.0.Q-STOD - [SkillMonitored, Marked for Route Register|SK:80029]~~<br/>
2019-12-02 08:53:41,952 INFO  [35] PRO.0.SMGR.1 - [RegisterSkill|SK:80029]~~<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "**" occurring twice in your sample data are your mistake
and they should not be there.
Maybe you wanted to mark these line as **bold**.

I also assume that `<br/>` in your sample are actually *newline* chars.

To do your task, start from `import re`, it will be used soon.

Them define the following generator:

```
def myReader(file_name):
    outRow = ''
    for row in open(file_name, 'r'):
        row = row.strip()
        if row[-2:] == '~~':
            outRow += row[0:-2]
            yield outRow
            outRow = ''
        else:
            outRow += row
```

It concatenates "continuation" lines (not ending with "~~")
to the previous line and returns (yields) complete lines.

Note: if you want to keep *newline* chars after "non-terminating" lines,
change the last line to:

```
outRow += row + '\n'
```

And finally, assuming that you have a **single** input file, to create
and load your DataFrame, you should run:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['eventtime', 'FileType', 'msg_type',
    'thread_num', 'msg_lyr', 'message', 'colorcode'])
pat = re.compile(r'(?P<Date>[\d-]+ [\d:]+,\d+) (?P<msg_type>\w+) +'
    r'\[(?P<thread_num>\d+)\] (?P<msg_lyr>[\w.]+) +\- \[(?P<message>[^\]]+)')
myGen = myReader('log.txt')
for row in myGen:
    mtch = re.match(pat, row)
    if mtch:
        dat = mtch.group('Date').replace(',', '.')
        df.loc[len(df)] = pd.Series({'eventtime': dat, 'FileType': 'silogs',
            'msg_type': mtch.group('msg_type'), 'thread_num': mtch.group('thread_num'),
            'msg_lyr': mtch.group('msg_lyr'), 'message': mtch.group('message'),
            'colorcode': ''})
```

To cope with **more** files, move the above code to a function, changing
the constant file name into the name given by the parameter and call
this function for each source file name.

Of course, both creation of the empty DataFrame and regex compilation
should be performed once, before this loop.

## Edit following the comment

The reason the code works slowly is that for each source row:

- A *Series* is created.
- Then it is appended to the *DataFrame* created before.

Much quicker solution is to:

- Create a list of lists (each embedded list for a source row).
- Append the **whole list** to the *DataFrame*.

So change the code to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['eventtime', 'FileType', 'msg_type',
    'thread_num', 'msg_lyr', 'message', 'colorcode'])
pat = re.compile(r'(?P<Date>[\d-]+ [\d:]+,\d+) (?P<msg_type>\w+) +'
    r'\[(?P<thread_num>\d+)\] (?P<msg_lyr>[\w.]+) +\- \[(?P<message>[^\]]+)')
tbl = []
myGen = myReader('log.txt')
for row in myGen:
    mtch = re.match(pat, row)
    if mtch:
        dat = mtch.group('Date').replace(',', '.')
        tbl.append({'eventtime': dat, 'FileType': 'silogs',
            'msg_type': mtch.group('msg_type'), 'thread_num': mtch.group('thread_num'),
            'msg_lyr': mtch.group('msg_lyr'), 'message': mtch.group('message'),
            'colorcode': ''})
df = df.append(tbl, ignore_index=True)
```

I measured the execution time of both variants and the above variant runs
almost 5 times quicker. For bigger source file the difference should be
even better.

Comment: Thanks @Valdi_Bo it has reduced my code significantly, but the issue is same the Ram